# Способы правильного округления до ближайшего целого в C

Tags: c, float, round

Какие в языке `C` существуют способы округлить значение числа с плавающей точкой до ближайшего целого?

Во многих источниках приводятся функции из семейства `round()`, которые должны находиться в `math.h`, однако в моем `math.h` таких функций нет. Наверное, это какая-то ошибка, и на самом деле в источниках рассматривается `C++`, а не `C`.

Я пытаюсь побороть проблему, которая появляется при конвертации вида:

```
size_t -> float -> size_t
```

У меня есть примерно следующее:

```
typedef struct s_animation_state
{
    size_t first,
           last;
    float current;
} animation_state;
```

Я хочу делать так:

```
void animation_processing(animation_state *const _state,
                          const float _dt)
{
    // ...
    _state->current += dt;
    if (_state->current > _state->last)
    {
        _state->current = _state->first;
    }
}
```

То есть, я проигрываю анимацию независимо от `fps`. Проблема возникает в тот момент, когда я хочу перевести проигрывание в начало диапазона, то есть, установить счетчик текущего кадра `current` на первый кадр диапазона проигрывания.

Может получится так:

```
current_frame = 100 000 000;
// current_frame == 99 999 999.7;
```

Из-а того, что число `100 000 000` не может быть представлено во `float`, выбирается ближайшее доступное значение `99 999 999.7`.

Когда я попытаюсь получить номер кадра, который нужно отобразить, у меня есть два пути:

- Просто отбросить дробную часть, выполнив преобразование `float -> size_t`;
- Округлить `float` до ближайшего целого.

Первый случай совершенно не годится, потому что это неточно, а в некоторых случаях я и вообще могу вылезти за диапазон, поймав ошибку сегментации.

Для второго случая мне каким-то образом нужно округлить значение до ближайшего целого. В `math.h` языка `C` нет подходящих функций. Есть функции для округления до ближайшего меньшего целого и для округления до ближайшего большего целого.

Ручной вариант округления:

```
s = f + 0.5f;
```

Тоже не годится. Потому, что если счетчик текущего кадра, допустим, равен `1.51`, то после такого преобразования я получу кадр `2`. Это неточно.

Подскажите, что делать.

Comment: "*если счетчик текущего кадра, допустим, равен 1.51, то после такого преобразования я получу кадр 2. Это неточно.*" - а что вы хотите при этом получить? Какое значение для вас будет точным?

Comment: Меня вполне устраивает простой отброс дробной части. Но проблема заключается в том, что записывая целое число во `float` я с достаточно высокой вероятностью получу значение, которое меньше данного целого числа: `7 -> 6.99993`, и в этом случае простой отброс дробной части приведет к смещению на единицу.

Comment: То есть, проблему можно решать с разных сторон, но я не знаю, с какой стороны правильнее.

Comment: Почему счётчик дробный?

Comment: Дробный счетчик необходим потому, что позиция текущего кадра каждую итерацию цикла отрисовки сдвигается на величину времени отрисовки. Чтобы, допустим, анимация проигрывалась с одной и той же скоростью как при обновлении сцены 20 раз в секунду, так и при обновлении сцены 200 раз в секунду.

Comment: Откровенно - меня вообще "терзают смутные сомнения", что у вас `float` - в силу неверного проектирования. Почему он не целочисленный?

Comment: @Harry, как вы предлагаете правильно учитывать позицию текущего кадра при переменчивой частоте отрисовки?

Comment: А что, величина времени - величина не целая? И даже тогда - почему именно float, а не double?

Comment: `double` не решит проблему потери единицы. `float` используется потому, что время итерации отрисовки удобнее всего представлять именно во `float`.

Comment: Я же вашу задачу не знаю полностью - что вы меня спрашиваете, показав только какой-то кусочек - доска, гвозди, микроскоп... :) Скорее всего, нужен иной принцип расчетов. А если вам так удобнее - то, извините, вы ищете не решение, а как сделать так, чтоб все получилось, ничего не меняя.

Comment: Есть цикл отрисовки. В этом цикле каждый кадр считается `dt` - это время вывода последнего кадра. Это значение используется для многих вещей. Например, для просчета смещений: `x += dt * vx`. Так же `dt` используется для правильного просчета анимации. Собственно, вот.

Comment: Почему dt у вас с плавающей точкой? Почему не целое? Вы меряете его в каких-то милли, микро, наносекундах - ну и просчитывайте все как целое. По крайней мере номер кадра.

Comment: Потому что это удобно для просчетов, которые независимы от текущей частоты отрисовки. Например, в один момент отрисовка происходит с частотой 27 `fps`, а в другой с частотой 150 `fps`.

Comment: Видимо, мне нужно хранить индекс текущего кадра в `size_t` и завести дополнительную переменную типа `float`, в которой будет вестись учет того, как долго показывается кадр. Тогда я смогу сделать верную навигацию по кадрам без всяких извращений с преобразованиями, чтобы побороть проблему потери единицы при конвертациях `size_t -> float -> size_t` с простым отбрасыванием дробной части.

Comment: Наверное, луче целочисленные вещи считать целочисленно... И еще - у вас так и не было сформулировано **точное ТЗ** на округление. Для 1.51 вас устраивал отброс дробной части, для 1.99 - нет. Где начало того конца, которым оканчивается начало? Как только вы сформулируете - хотя бы для себя - **точное** ТЗ, а не просто "хочу чего-то" (кстати, `round()` округлил бы 1.51 до 2), так сразу будет понятно, как этого добиться. Где у вас должна была быть граница округления - меньшее - вниз, большее - вверх?

Comment: Я уже примерно понял, как нужно решать проблему. Хранить индекс текущего кадра в виде `float` - плохая идея, и я ошибочно полагал, что эту проблему можно решить преобразованиями.

Comment: Рекомендация на будущее: в следующий раз время считать не дробным прибавлением, а прибавлением целочисленных тиков (к примеру, один тик может быть равен 0.01 с).

Answer (score 1):

В общем, после тщательного анализа я смог детально понять, в чем заключается проблема.

Если для хранения индекса текущего кадра использовать число с плавающей запятой, то проблема либо вообще не имеет решения, либо это решение будет крайне нерациональным.

Основная проблема возникает при переводе счетчика текущего кадра на начальный кадр диапазона:

```
current = first;
```

Здесь происходит преобразование:

```
size_t -> float
```

Которое может дать такой результат:

```
1 000 000 -> 999 999.9f
```

В этом и заключается основная проблема. Теперь, когда я захочу определить индекс текущего кадра для отрисовки, мне придется выполнить преобразование:

```
float -> size_t
```

Я могу просто отбросить дробную часть, тогда вместо `1 000 000` я получу `999 999`, потеряв единицу.

Либо же я могу осуществить округление до ближайшего целого:

```
s = f + 0.5f;
```

Такое решение тоже является плохим. Например, счетчик текущего кадра будет иметь значение `0.51f`, это приведет к отрисовке кадра `1`. Таким образом, первый и последний кадры диапазона будут проигрываться в два раза меньше того времени, которое нужно.

Решением это проблемы может стать следующее:

```
typedef struct s_animation_state
{
    size_t first,
           current,
           last;
    float fps,
          t;
} animation_state;

// ...

void animation_processing(animation_state *const _state,
                          const float _dt)
{
    _state->t += _dt * _state->fps;
    if (_state->t > 1.f)
    {
        _state->current += _state->t + 0.5f;
        _state->t = 0.f;
        if (_state->current > _state->last)
        {
            _state->current -= (_state->last - _state->first) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В данном случаи можно использовать `uint_64t`. для целой  части используйте старшие 54 бита , для дробной младшие 10 бит. Имхо не используйте `float` в С , `int` наше все

Answer (score 1):

Видел [ваш ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/938870/193189) с утверждением про решённость, но хочу добавить несколько слов по сути.

I. Относительно функции `round`. В C99 в <math.h> определены аж три функции для этого: `round`, `rint` и `nearbyint`, со слегка разным поведением. Все три округляют к ближайшему целому, но при дробной части равной ровно 0.5 round() округляет в направлении от нуля, а rint() и nearbyint() - к ближайшему чётному (гауссово округление).

В C89 их ещё не было, хотя много реализаций уже поддерживало. Если библиотека вашего компилятора такого не знает... да, я могу поверить, что в 2019 году ещё кто-то может не поддерживать стандарт 1999-го года, но мне это представляется просто дикостью. (Случаи embedded в особо тесных ресурсах - не рассматриваем.)

II. Вы пишете:

> Из-а того, что число 100 000 000 не может быть представлено во float, выбирается ближайшее доступное значение 99 999 999.7.

Это просто неверно (даже с точки зрения здравого смысла - ну как "ближайшее доступное" может быть нецелым, если подаётся целое)? Может, вы хотели сказать наоборот - вместо 99_999_999.7 выбирается 100_000_000? Тогда можно поверить.

Во float, если это 32-битный двоичный IEEE754 формат, проблема есть на таких числах, но выглядит иначе: дискрет между соседними представимыми значениями становится больше 1. После 100_000_000 - следующее представимое уже равно 100_000_008, и промежуточные округляются к какому-то из них. Если это проблема, переходите на double, там аналогичное начинается при достижении 17-значных чисел.

Но чтобы из size_t получать дробное число - это что-то нереальное. Подозреваю, что вы скрыли, что речь идёт не про кадры, а, например, секунды. Там уже возможно значение типа 1.51, с соответствующей кадровой позицией. Или же речь про вычисление промежуточных состояний (как для мультипликации), тогда слабо верится в такую платформу, где нет даже round().

> Ручной вариант округления:
>
> s = f + 0.5f;
>
> Тоже не годится. Потому, что если счетчик текущего кадра, допустим, равен 1.51, то после такого преобразования я получу кадр 2. Это неточно.

А какую вообще точность в данном случае вы предполагаете, если у вас значения имеют погрешность (не то 1.51, не то 1.49), а вам надо округлить до целого?

Вариант типа `int(f+0.5f)` практически эквивалентен round(), кроме типа результата и поведения в супер-маргинальных случаях. Если этого недостаточно - извините, постановка задачи в принципе некорректна. Но в ней, похоже, путаетесь сами, или слишком пытаетесь скрыть всякие non-disclosure детали, что не можете корректно описать ситуацию.

III. Тип `float` - опять же, считаем, что это 32-битный двоичный IEEE754 - имеет точность только 6 десятичных цифр, если считать, какое число можно преобразовать в двоичный формат и обратно с округлением по умолчанию и получить то же число. (Для большинства значений сохраняется 7 цифр, но не для всех.) Если вы считаете доли секунды в длинном видео, этого точно недостаточно.

Какие есть альтернативы - их по сути две:
1) Переходить на double. Возможно, вам недоступно (если у вас нет `round()`, то неизвестно, что ещё вырезано).
2) Переходить на целые числа. Если у вас позиция времени в секундах, то целое её значение в миллисекундах - должно быть достаточно для большинства применений (вряд ли вы напрямую работаете со скоростной съёмкой, а даже суперпрогрессивного сейчас 100 кадров в секунду - это 10 значений между кадрами). 32 бит без знака хватит на 4.2 млн. секунд - около полутора месяцев.

Пока этого хватит. В принципе, ваш вопрос вообще должен был быть замодерирован, потому что изложен с явным внутренним противоречием.